# Executing command line with other user

Tags: command-line, wvdial, multiple-users

I'm struggling with a problem, i'm using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, i have a command line "wvdial brt" wich i need to execute with every boot from my computer, i have 2 users in my computer and i have to execute this command from any of them, i tried to include this command in /etc/rc.local but when i log in with the another user the command doesn't work, is there any other place more recommended to insert this command line? i'm doing something wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 is beyond end of life so support is going to be minimal at best. I suggest a more recent version of ubuntu.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I think this is version idependent.

Answer (score 2):

Run `gedit ~/.config/autostart/wvdial.desktop` logged in as the first user and paste the following code inside the file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=wvdial brt
Name=WVDIAL
```

Repeat the process logged in as the second user. The command will be executed when the users log in.